# Working with numba in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, installation, osgeo4w, anaconda

I am trying to install the python library numba with pip from the OSGeo4W shell, but I haven't been able to do it. The only way I could do this was through the anaconda installer. but since Anaconda and OSGeo4W have their own versions of python, this solution is not viable to me.

I need to use this library in a qgis script, Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Since the last version of Numba (0.35) you can install Numba also using pip. (This won't install e.g. the cuda lib for you, as the installation via conda does)

```
pip install numba
```

Like this, you can actually install the package in your QGIS Python. But there is a problem with actually using it from within the QGIS console. See [this question on SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255452/is-it-possible-to-use-numba-in-qgis)